# In how many different ways can I arrange $n$ girls and $m$ boys with no at least $k$ boys or $k$ girls sit next to each other?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

For example, we have $n = 5$ boys and $m = 6$ girls, we don't want $k \le min(n,  m)$ | $k = 3$ boys or girls to sit next to each other.

A valid arrangement: $BBGGBGGBGG$

An invalid arrangement: $BBBGGBGGBGG$ - There are $3$ boys sit next to each other.

And we ignore the permutation between any group of boys and girls so $BBGGBGGBGG$ is considered only $1$ way

Comment: elcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Note that sometimes it is impossible, for example if you have 10 boys and 2 girls and k=3, because in any arrangement you use there will be 3 or more boys sitting next to each other. I think for the general case you must have $k>\frac{|m-n|}{2}-2$ But I might be wrong in this one

Comment: I'm sorry, It should be like this $k \le min(n, m)$.

Comment: @FareedAF If that scenario happens, the answer can only be 0 because there are no way we can arrange, right?

Comment: Yes thats what I meant by impossible, 0 ways

Comment: But I still think that, $k \le min(n, m)$ is wrong.
Try it with 10 boys 3 girls and k=3 for example, would it work?

Comment: @FareedAF No, it wouldn't. Sorry, I misunderstood your statement.